# How to convert cuboid to mesh efficiently

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, opencascade

```
cuboids = 
Table[Cuboid @@ (pts = RandomReal[100, {2, 3}]), {i, 10000}];
```

Method1:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
r = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]] & /@ 
cuboids[[1 ;; 100]];]
```

Method1, Sometimes, on my macbook pro, costs 5 seconds, this is not a stable method.

A baseline is to convert 10000 random cuboids to a mesh object of 60000 polygons in 10 seconds. Import this file in "MeshRegion" Option costs little time.

like method2:

```
In[53]:= AbsoluteTiming[Export["test.obj", Graphics3D@cuboids];]

Out[53]= {8.00617, Null}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cuboids = Table[Cuboid @@ (pts = RandomReal[100, {2, 3}]), {i, 10000}];

cuboids /. 
   Cuboid[{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}] :> 
    MeshRegion[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}, {x1, y2, z1},
      {x1, y1, z2}, {x2, y1, z2}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x1, y2, z2}},
        {Polygon[{{4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6},
          {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.330509, Null}

Replace `MeshRegion` with `BoundaryMeshRegion`

> {16.3816, Null}

Comment: great, I like it, my first thought is that the pMin,pMax of Cuboid are not so direct to draw the polygons. Thanks for your work.

Comment: If we use RegionUnion to comine these meshes will cost me 8 seconds, in this situation,=,a whole mesh. kglr's solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the
[OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) (that ships with Wolfram Language since version 12.1 or from
[GitHub](https://github.com/WolframResearch/OpenCascadeLink))
for this:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
cuboids = 
  Table[Cuboid @@ (pts = RandomReal[100, {2, 3}]), {i, 10000}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 r = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]] & /@
     cuboids;]

{36.422, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[
 s = OpenCascadeShape /@ cuboids;
 bmeshs = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh /@ s;
 ]
{11.1387, Null}

bmeshs // Length
10000

FreeQ[bmeshs, $Failed]
True

#["Wireframe"] & /@ RandomChoice[bmeshs, {10}]
```

Comment: Thanks for point out ["OpenCascadeLink`"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html)!

Answer (score 2):

Getting single `MeshRegion` using all 10000 cuboids seems to be faster than generating a `MeshRegion` object for each cuboid:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[100, {10000, 2, 3}];
cuboids = Cuboid @@@ pts;

cuboidsToMeshReg = Module[{indices, 
     faceindices = {{3, 7, 5, 1}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {5, 7, 8, 6}, {4, 8, 7, 3}, 
       {2, 4, 3, 1}, {2, 6, 8, 4}}, 
     meshcoords = Join @@ (Tuples[Transpose@{##}] & @@@ #)}, 
    indices = Join @@ (faceindices + 8 # & /@ Range[0, Length[#] - 1]); 
    MeshRegion[meshcoords, Polygon @ indices]] &;

mreg = cuboidsToMeshReg @ cuboids; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.157844
> ```

```
MeshCellCount[mreg, 2]
```

> ```
> 60000
> ```

Comment: Nice, thanks, sometimes, I just need a whole mesh.